# Data from Controller not visible in View - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting with MCV in ASP and just on my first try I'm having problems when parsing data from controller to view. BTW, I'm using a entity model from a MySql Database.

Controller

```vb
Namespace MvcRad
    Public Class ProyectosController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller


        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim ed As New visrunEntities
            ViewData("values") = From p In ed.proyectos _
                             Select p
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

View

```vb
<div>
   <% For Each p In ViewData("values")
           p.Codigo()%> <br/>
   <%Next%>
</div>
```

I tried printing a random value to know if it was looping like this (There are 4 records on table):

```vb
<div>
   <% For Each c In ViewData("values")%> 
            A<br/>
   <%Next%>
</div>
```

And it works, because I get:

```
A
A
A
A
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cast the `ViewData("values")` to list of ed.proyectos _ to print the properties of it

Comment: If you're talking about this: 
    ViewData("values") = (From p In ed.proyectos _
                                 Select p).ToList()
 I already tried it, and it didn't work.

Comment: No I'm talking about casting the list in view itself ex: For Each c In ViewData("values") as Type of proyectos